# Remove matched tags in html files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing

I have some html files, each of which contains

```
<td id="MenuTD" style="vertical-align: top;"> 
...
</td>
```

where `...` can contain anything, and `</td>` matches `<td id="MenuTD" style="vertical-align: top;">`. I would like to remove this part from the html files.

Similarly, I may also want to remove some other tags in the files.

How shall I program that in Python?

I am looking at `HTMLParser` module in Python 2.7, but haven't figured out  if that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You have two options, depending on what you want to do with the element you're removing.

Set up:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html>
    <header>
        <title>A test</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="MenuTD" style="vertical-align: top;"> 
                    Stuff here <a>with a link</a>
                    <p>Or paragraph tags</p>
                    <div>Or a DIV</div>
                </td>
                <td>Another TD element, without the MenuTD id</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

---

- Option 1 is to use the [`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) method. Using this, you will retain a copy of your extracted element so that you can utilize it later in your application:

Code:

```
menu_td = soup.find(id="MenuTD").extract()
```

At this point, the element you are removing has been saved to the `menu_td` variable. Do what you want with that. Your HTML in the `soup` variable no longer contains your element though:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
 <header>
  <title>
   A test
  </title>
 </header>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Another TD element, without the MenuTD id
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Everything in the `MenuTD` element has been removed. You can see it is still in the `menu_td` variable though:

```
print(menu_td.prettify())
```

Outputs:

```
<td id="MenuTD" style="vertical-align: top;">
 Stuff here
 <a>
  with a link
 </a>
 <p>
  Or paragraph tags
 </p>
 <div>
  Or a DIV
 </div>
</td>
```

- Option 2: Utilize [`.decompose()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose). If you do not need a copy of the removed element, you can utilize this function to remove it from the document and destroy the contents.

Code:

```
soup.find(id="MenuTD").decompose()
```

It doesn't return anything (unlike `.extract()`). It does, however, remove the element from your document:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
 <header>
  <title>
   A test
  </title>
 </header>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Another TD element, without the MenuTD id
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```